# Is there a quick way to make dummy files and git commit them to simulate work?

Tags: git, commit

For testing git functions, I'd like to quickly make any number of commits without manually making changes and committing them individually. Right now, I have to manually do the following separate commands for as many commits as I want:

```
$ touch test1

$ git add .

$ git commit -m "Add test1"
[fix2 91efb1b] Add test1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test1
```

This of course gives the outcome I'm looking for (cheap commits to test git flow commands) but it takes a lot of typing. Is it possible to automate this or is there a command that does this already?

Comment: Self-answering a too-broad question doesn't really make it any more on-topic.

Comment: @chepner how is it too broad? I was looking for a simple command or script solution and found none. Then made my own.

Comment: It's too broad because it's not a question; it's just a request for code.

Comment: @chepner It can be reworded into a question without requesting code. No need to downvote something that is still useful.

Comment: This isn't a blog. As a question, this just says "I have a task to complete; how would I write this?"

Comment: @chepner that's what questions on SO are... "I'm trying to accomplish this thing. Does anyone know how?" "how do i do whatever" and then it turns out I figure out a way, just as if anyone else figured out a way. I don't see the problem here as it's like every other question. And the answer is just providing a solution in case someone else has a similar need.

Comment: No, that's *not* what a good Stack Overflow question looks like, which provides *existing* code, along with the observed and desired outcome. All you have is a desired outcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177754/discussion-between-gaetawoo-and-chepner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using a simple bash script I saved into a $PATH directory (or you don't have to):

```
>hackhackhack.sh
----------------

#!/bin/bash

for ((i=1;i<=$2;i++));
do
    fname="$1$i" 
    touch $fname
    git add $fname
    git commit -m "Add $fname"
done
```

It takes a filename and a number as input in that order; creates the file, adds it to the index, makes the commit, and starts over or ends.

The output looks like this:

```
$ . hackhackhack.sh dummy 5
[master e7a9f93] Add dummy1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy1
[master 0726230] Add dummy2
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy2
[master 94a83a2] Add dummy3
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy3
[master b38c825] Add dummy4
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy4
[master b406bb5] Add dummy5
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dummy5
```

Works great for me! Enjoy!